"Усмотрение автора" при выборе знаков. О сочетании "А что(,) если..."
Обратимся к конкретной теме: меня интересует постановка запятой в сочетании А что(,) если...).

Надо посмотреть правило, а правила нет. Но в Сети есть очень уверенные ответы, в том числе и с нашего форума: 1 и 2. Там правила, грамматические толкования и т.д. Вот пример предложений, которые обсуждались:

(1) А что(,) если полным семьям педагогов дать возможность внеочередного вступления в жилищно-строительный кооператив? (2) А что(,) если он мне не поверит?

Смотрю Нацкорпус: пользователи пишут, как кому захочется (с запятой и без).

А в Справочной службе говорят так:
№ 239828. Нужно ли ставить запятую в этой фразе: "А что если вы не все 
предусмотрели? ОТВЕТ. Запятая ставится на усмотрение автора.


Тогда зачем на форумах дают вполне определенные, да еще однозначные ответы, если все так просто: пишите как кому нравится. Я же считаю, что авторский выбор должен быть обоснованным.


Вопросы:
Что такое усмотрение автора (как вы понимаете)? Как обосновать постановку запятой в приведенных предложениях?

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
